# Continuous function on a metric space/topology

Tags: functions, continuity

X a metric space. Let $\gamma$1, $\gamma$2 : [0,1] → X `be two continuous paths such that` $\gamma$1 (1) = $\gamma$2 (0). `Consider the map`$\gamma$ : [0,1] → X `deﬁned as` $\gamma$(t) =  $\gamma$1 (2t), `if` t∈ [0,$\frac{1}{2}$)
`or` $\gamma$(t) = $\gamma$2 (2t−1), `if` t ∈ [$\frac{1}{2}$,1]  `Show that` $\gamma$ `is a continuous path in` X.

How should I show if this is continuous? 
Can I use the "usual" definitions, as the epsilon-delta or the limit definition? Or do I have to use something else since X is a metric space?

Any guidence or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are continuous over $[0,1]$, $\gamma$ behaves as $\gamma_1$ over $[0,\frac12)$ and as $\gamma_2$ over $[\frac12,1]$. So it is sufficient to check the continuity at the join of the two paths i.e. at $x=\frac12$ which can be checked by using the left and right hand limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is also true more generally if $X$ is a topological space not necessarily metrizable.

---

In general if $A,B$ are closed subsets of topological space $Y$ and we have function $f:A\to X$ continuous on $A$, function $g:B\to X$ continuous on $B$ such that $f$ and $g$ coincide on $A\cap B$ then the function $h=f\cup g:A\cup B\to X$ is continuous as well.

To prove that $h$ is continuous it is enough to show that the preimage of a closed set  $F\subseteq X$ is a closed subset of $Y$.

This preimage is the set $f^{-1}(F)\cup g^{-1}(F)$, so we are ready if we can prove that the sets $f^{-1}(F)$ and $g^{-1}(F)$ are closed.

Since $f$ is continuous the set $f^{-1}(F)$ is a closed set in space $A$ which means that it can be written as $P\cap A$ where $P$ is a closed set in $Y$.

But that means that $f^{-1}(F)=P\cap A$ is an intersection of two closed sets: $A$ and $P$.

We conclude that $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed.

Similarly we find that $g^{-1}(F)$ is closed and we are ready.

---

You can apply that here on $A=[0,0.5]$ and $B=[0.5,1]$ wich are closed subsets of $Y:=[0,1]$.